# Saving each row of SQL query result as text file

Tags: python, sql

I am connecting to MySQL using Python, and I was wondering if there was any way which I could save each row in the results of the SQL query as its own text file.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, it's absolutely impossible to write to a file via Python. It's just not implemented in the language. Can't be done. Sorry! (And if you buy that, I have a bridge to sell you...)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have made it more clear. Using the output from a SQL query, how do I save each of the rows in the output as its own text file?I would assume a for loop, but I am not sure how to actually implement it.

Comment: So, you want a bunch of text files with what amounts to one row of data (presumably in csv form) each?

Comment: Text would be preferable, but CSV could work as well.

Comment: So, just write to a bunch of files, then. There's absolutely nothing stopping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're so insisted to writing each row record into individual text file, here's one way to do it:

```
...
c.execute('select * from your_table')
for i, row in enumerate(c):
    # inefficienctly write each row to a new file using index as name
    with open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write('{}'.format(row))
...
```

You can also loop through `fetchall()`, or iterate `fetch_one()`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!. I am running some topic modelling and classification algorithms, and the tool I am using works better if the text files are separated.

Comment: @SagarSamtani, glad it helps. And yes I guess everyone's use case is just different :)